# After FlashWindow, click the window and the taskbar remains highlight (orange)

Tags: winapi, mfc, window, windows-xp

When I click the application shortcut, if the program is already open, I will show the program and enable FlashWindow. (**FlashWindow(true)**;)

After blinking once, the taskbar is highlighted.
Theoretically, clicking on the application window would unhighlight the taskbar.
But it doesn't.

There is no problem when the window is minimized.
But it doesn't work when the window is already **displayed**.

I tried to get all the window handles of the application based on the process id and activated them one by one, but that didn't work either.
For this step I printed the log and used **GetForegroundWindow** to confirm that the change did happen.

How to solve this problem?

Is there any other way to make the taskbar blink only once without keeping it highlighted?

Comment: Activating a window is possibly part of the issue. What you want to do instead is making the running application instance's top-level window the *foreground* window. You only have one attempt to do it. Use it wisely.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. From [FlashWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow)  doc, it said Flashes the specified window one time. It does not change the active state of the window.  Which message do you put `FlashWindow`  under? You can add some code to the question to describe the details.